# Qt 5.3.1 introduced issue with QSqlTableModel and QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt, qsqltablemodel, qsortfilterproxymodel, qt5.3

I am using QSortFilterProxyModel for a lot of data models and it worked fine. After updating from Qt5.3.0 to Qt5.3.1 this changed partly.

One of my GUI panels uses a QTreeView attached to a QSortFilterProxyModel attached to a QSqlTableModel. The SQL model is assigned to a database table with about 60000 rows and 6 common columns.

Using Qt5.3.0 data loading was simple... it needed a few seconds to load the data (used task manager as network traffic monitor) and another second to display the data in the QTreeView.

Using Qt5.3.1 that became pain... it still needs a few seconds to load the data but then it blocks an entire CPU core for multiple minutes (making the application unresponsive) before data finally appears in the view.

This problem does not appear using custom models (derived from abstract table model) with similar row counts.

I also tried the same with a plain QSqlTableModel and a default constructed QSortFilterProxyModel (which means no filtering takes place at all)... still loading needs mutiple minutes. This is the code I use:

```
sqlTableModel = new QSqlTableModel(nullptr, QSqlDatabase::database(connectionName));

proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
proxyModel->setSourceModel(sqlTableModel);

tableView = new QTableView();
tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
tableView->setModel(proxyModel);

sqlTableModel->database().open();
sqlTableModel->setTable("table_name");
sqlTableModel->select();
```

I found two workarounds. However they are not powerful enough to do what I am currently doing using the proxy model:

1. Using QSqlTableModel sorting and filtering (WHERE and ORDER BY based).
2. Disabling sorting by `setSortingEnabled(false);`

Does someone know the problem? Is there some better workaround?

Comment: I haven't encountered this myself, but this sounds like a regression. Try Qt 5.3.2 which was just released -- does this issue still persist? If so, perhaps you'd want to stick to Qt 5.3.0 for now. Also please report this to http://bugreports.qt-project.org/ so that the Qt devs are aware of the issue.

Comment: It seems Qt5.3.2 doesn't solve the problem. I'll write a bug report.

Comment: Here it is: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41401. I am curious when/if they care about that showstopper.